# Search Display Controller error in UITableViewController in Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I have `UITableViewController` there is `Search Bar and Search Display Controller`. When I try typing something in the search and my code change data in array `arrayForSearchTable` the application crushes. This array need for display results in table. Error:

`*** Assertion failure in -[UISearchResultsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3262.1/UITableView.m:6101`

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier SearchCityCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

I did verification array `testArrayForSearchTable` that is a copy of `arrayForSearchTable`. Contents of the array displays - data is correct, normally displayed:

```
************
utfURL: http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=s
************
City: Sagamihara, Japan, Country: JP, ZMW: 00000.6.47680`
City: Sacramento, California, Country: US, ZMW: 94203.1.99999
City: Safi, Morocco, Country: MA, ZMW: 00000.1.60185
..................
```

What is wrong?

My code:

```
import UIKit

class AddFavCityTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var arrayForSearchTable: [Dictionary<String, String>] = []
var myAPI:APIController = APIController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println("Current count in result array: \(arrayForSearchTable.count)")
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if searchDisplayController.active {
        searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        //reloadTable("")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayForSearchTable.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchCityCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "SearchCityCell")
    }

    let cellCity: String? = (arrayForSearchTable[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary).valueForKey("Name") as? String
    cell.textLabel.text = cellCity

    let cellCountry: String? = (arrayForSearchTable[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary).valueForKey("Country") as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = cellCountry

    return cell
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {

    reloadTable(searchString)
    return true
}

func reloadTable(searchString: String) {

    var urlPath: String = "http://autocomplete.wunderground.com/aq?query=\(searchString)"
    println("************")
    println("urlPath: \(urlPath)")

    var receivedCitiesArray: NSArray = ((myAPI.jsonParsingWeather(urlPath)).valueForKey("RESULTS")?) as NSArray

    var cityInSearchList = [String: String]()

    // Test array, copy of arrayForSearchTable for cheking loop
    var testArrayForSearchTable: [Dictionary<String, String>] = []

    for tempArray in receivedCitiesArray {
        var tempDict = tempArray as NSDictionary
        cityInSearchList["Country"] = tempDict.valueForKey("c") as String!
        cityInSearchList["Name"] = tempDict.valueForKey("name") as String!
        cityInSearchList["ZMW"]  = tempDict.valueForKey("zmw") as String!
        testArrayForSearchTable += cityInSearchList
        arrayForSearchTable += cityInSearchList
    }


    //Loop for cheking result array
    println("************")
    for tempArray2 in testArrayForSearchTable {
        var testCity = (tempArray2 as NSDictionary).valueForKey("Name") as String
        var testCountry = (tempArray2 as NSDictionary).valueForKey("Country") as String
        var testZMW = (tempArray2 as NSDictionary).valueForKey("ZMW") as String
        println("City: \(testCity), Country: \(testCountry), ZMW: \(testZMW)")
    }


    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Instead

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchCityCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

write:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchCityCell") as UITableViewCell!
```

Comment: I think I have the same problem now...but if I use the second method you wrote (without the indexPath) how can I access the objects to show in the data source array?